# "Received status code 400" after apollo-server deploy to heroku

Tags: mongodb, git, heroku, apollo

If I run localy `npm start` - everything is ok

If I run `git subtree push --prefix server heroku-server master` - Build succeeded!

When I open `https://tmdb-apollo.herokuapp.com/` - `"error": "Response not successful: Received status code 400"`

If I still do a query or mutation - it works! magic! (but I do not have autocomplete and `shema` sidebar on the right is always spinning)

Github repo [here](https://github.com/kstulgys/tmdb-apollo)

I suspect it has something to do with my `MongoDB` connection setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been nearly 3 days till I found a solution:
Need to add `introspection: true`

```
// Set up Apollo Server
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  dataSources,
  context,
  introspection: true,
})
```