# Can't deploy apollo-server to NOW

Tags: apollo, apollo-server, vercel

If I cd `server` and run `now` it gets deployed to `https://server-91vnej46w.now.sh/`

When I open this url I expect to see a graphql playground but instead I see a `src` folder

[Deploying with Zeit Now](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/deployment/now.html#env-variables) apollo docs doesn't help

Github repo [here](https://github.com/kstulgys/tmdb-apollo)

Deployment to heroku doesn't work as well: [here's the post with an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53606573/received-status-code-400-after-apollo-server-deploy-to-heroku).

Comment: Were you able to find a resolution? I am having the exact same issue.

Comment: Nah. I'm using heroku 

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not have a `now.json` configuration. This file would tell `now` how to deploy your application. If this configuration was not defined then `now` would have just uploaded the files.
The GitHub repo you linked doesn't have a `now.json` file so this is likely the case.
[Now deployment configuration docs](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/configuration)